# Changing row method for a JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, row, listener

I need a method that executes when I change the row in a `JTable`. How do I achieve that? There is a listener for a `JTable` but it is used when the table is changed, not when you move accross the table. (I am rather new to Java). Can anyone help?

Comment: If by "row change" you mean the row's selection change then see [Users selection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) section in [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial. Basically you need to attach a `ListSelectionListener` to the table's selection model.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I have realized that when you move accros a table you are "selecting" cells, then it is easy to get the row or column numbers. So, thank you. I am into that right now.